# Format msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

--SQL format

```
Declare @body As nvarchar(max)=N'<HTML>'
        +N'<p>Hi '+@userId+'</p>New amendment for act <b>'+@title+'</b> is added'
        +N'<p>This amendment include changes to the Section: <b>'+@sectionid+'</b> and Title: <b>'+@title+'.</b></p>'
        +N'<p>You are receiving this message because you have added change alert notification on Section: <b>'+@sectionid+'.</b></p>'
        +N'</HTML>'
```

on Receive email

```
<HTML><p>Hi zubairpayab</p>New amendment for act <b>Amendment of section 2C</b> is added<p>This amendment include changes to the Section: <b>2</b> and Title: <b>Amendment of section 2C.</b></p><p>You are receiving this message because you have added change alert notification on Section: <b>2.</b></p></HTML>
```

[image]

Can you help me to correct the format

Comment: You need to show your full code for sending the email. It looks like you are sending it as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Body format as HTML while calling the sp_send_dbmail

```
EXEC dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MyMailProfile',
                        @recipients = 'receiver@gmail.com',
                        @copy_recipients = 'cc@gmail.com',
                        @body = 'HTML Body Content',
                        @body_format = 'HTML',
                        @subject = 'My Mail Subject';
```